# Sort MySQL Results Alphabetically

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an online book database and I have this php script to search through the mysql db and get results. For some reason, the results are random. Is there any one to sort them by author?  (Name for author field=search_author in the form and Author in the mysql column.)

```
    $search_titles=$_POST["search_titles"];
$search_authors=$_POST["search_authors"];
$search_shelf=$_POST["search_shelf"];
$search_genre=$_POST["search_genre"];

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//build the mySQL query string. Required something like this (the uppercase kwords are SQL commands): 
//SELECT * FROM booklist WHERE Title LIKE 'Computing' AND Author LIKE 'borg'
//Instead of AND, you might want to try OR

$query_string ="SELECT * FROM booklist WHERE ";

$insert_AND = false;  //a flag to indicate when an AND keyword needs to be inserted

//only include search terms/fields that have been specified in form (not empty, but note that a bunch of spaces will be treated as non-empty ... to-fix by validating form)
if ($search_titles != ""){
    $query_string .= "Title LIKE '%".$search_titles."%'";    //the % is a wild card
    $insert_AND = true;
}   

if ($search_genre != ""){
    $query_string .= "Genre LIKE '%".$search_genre."%'";    //the % is a wild card
    $insert_AND = true;
}   

if ($search_authors != ""){
    if ($insert_AND) $query_string .= " AND ";    //you might want to 
    $query_string .= "Author LIKE '%".$search_authors."%'"; 
    $insert_AND = true;
}       

if ($search_shelf != ""){
    if ($insert_AND) $query_string .= " AND ";
    $query_string .= "ShelfNumber LIKE '%".$search_shelf."%'"; 
}       

//echo($query_string);
//done building the query string
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//perform the query on the db using the query string 
$result_array = mysql_query($query_string )or die(mysql_error());

//The sql server will return a 2D array containing the results (if any).
//Output these to the browser
if(mysql_num_rows($result_array)==0){  //i.e. an empty array was returned, meaning no results
    echo "NO MATCHES FOUND";
}else{      //mathces found

    echo mysql_num_rows($result_array) . " results found <BR><HR>";     

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_array)) {   //loop through the array, each time displaying a result from the next row, until all rows have been displayed
        echo "<B>Title: </B>" . $row['Title'] . "<BR>";
        echo "<B>Author: </B>" . $row['Author']. "<BR>";
        echo "<B>Genre: </B>" . $row['Genre']. "<BR>";
        echo "<B>Shelf: </B>". $row['ShelfNumber']. "<BR>";
        //note that the other fields (e.g. genre, etc) are also in the array since in the query string '*' (i.e. all fields) was specified.
        echo "<HR>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your query put this:

```
ORDER BY search_author ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to *order* it by *author* you would want to add `ORDER BY` clause to your query:

```
if ($search_authors != ""){
    if ($insert_AND) $query_string .= " AND ";    //you might want to 
    $query_string .= "Author LIKE '%".$search_authors."%' ORDER BY Author ASC"; 
    $insert_AND = true;
}
```

[MySQL Documentation: Sorting options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html)

Referring to the existing answer, it's incorrectly understood, as an questioner stated:

> Name for author field=search_author in the form and Author in the mysql column.

It should be `ORDER BY Author ASC` not `ORDER BY search_author ASC`.

**EDIT 1:**

In order to make it work properly in case it's added query, you should put `if ($search_authors != ""){` below `if ($search_shelf != ""){`